# [Guice/MissingImplementation]: No implementation was bound

Tags: java, dependency-injection, guice, dropwizard-guice

I am trying to implement a simple app using Guice for DI.
The app has an interface *Shape* :

```
public interface Shape {
    void draw();
}
```

that is implemented by a class *Rectangle*.

```
public class Rectangle implements Shape{
    @Override
    public void draw() {
        System.out.printf("Shape is a rectangle");
    }
}
```

Then there is a class ShapeRequest that would inject *Shape* bean at runtime based on the explicit bindings I provide.

```
@Singleton
public class ShapeRequest {

    @AnnotatedRectangle
    private final Shape shape;

    @Inject
    public ShapeRequest(Shape shape) {
        System.out.println("Attempting injection");
        this.shape = shape;
    }

    public Shape getShape() {
        return shape;
    }

    public void action(){
        System.out.println(shape.getClass());
        shape.draw();
    }
}
```

Binding class (implements AbstractModule) is as follows:

```
@Override
protected void configure(){
    bind(Shape.class).annotatedWith(AnnotatedRectangle.class).to(Rectangle.class);
    bind(String.class).annotatedWith(Color.class).toInstance("GREEN");

}
```

To support the above, I have created an annotation:

```
@BindingAnnotation
@Target({ElementType.FIELD})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
public @interface AnnotatedRectangle {
}
```

Now in the client class:

```
Injector injector = Guice.createInjector(new AppModule());
ShapeRequest request=injector.getInstance(ShapeRequest.class);
```

Error:

```
Exception in thread "main" com.google.inject.ConfigurationException: Guice configuration errors:

1) [Guice/MissingImplementation]: No implementation for Shape was bound.

Did you mean?
    * Shape annotated with interface AnnotatedRectangle bound at AppModule.configure(AppModule.java:18)

Requested by:
1  : ShapeRequest.<init>(ShapeRequest.java:19)
      \_ for 1st parameter
     while locating ShapeRequest
```

What could be the issue here? I believe that I am explicitly specifying that a dependency of type *Shape* and annotation *AnnotatedRectangle* must be injected with an object of type *Rectangle* .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Put the `@AnnotatedRectangle` annotation to the constructor's parameter, not in the field:

```
private final Shape shape;

@Inject
public ShapeRequest(@AnnotatedRectangle Shape shape) {
    System.out.println("Attempting injection");
    this.shape = shape;
}
```

If you use contructor injection all the "metadata" of the injection must go to the construction. Guice attempts either constructor injection or field injection. Not both.

Also, I would replace `@BindingAnnotation` with `@Qualifier` as the JSR standard. Also according to [Guice](https://github.com/google/guice/wiki/BindingAnnotations):

> Guice's @BindingAnnotation is also used for this purpose in older
> code.

Comment: Ok, I guess what you meant is PARAMETER injection instead of CONSTRUCTOR/FIELD injection,  and yes, it's working for PARAMETER injection the way I wanted it to be. The point that Guice attempts either constructor or field injection (and not both at once) is what I missed out.